# AngularJS2 in PHP Apache

Tags: apache, angular

Today is my first day on AngularJS. I am following few tutorials on AngularJS v.2 with JavaScript. There is a prerequisite of Node.js. My development environment is PHP MySQL Apache (Xampp).

My question is, can I **write & run** angular app on apache without node.js?

Comment: You can if you want to link the js files and write everything in ES5 but why would you want to do that? Install node and use typescript.

Comment: You'll want to use nodejs as part of your client build chain, but you could still use PHP on your server. Is there an issue with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

angular2 and its ecosystem heavily depend on npm and node. While you theoretically could develop your application in a non-node environment, it would be a nightmare to set up and maintain.
Setting up a proper tool-chain would take ages if at all possible.

**It'd be a total waste of time and a painful experience. Ending with a frustrated you setting up node.**

Edit: your backend can be xampp based just fine! There's no need to use a node based production environment.